# Kotlin invoke constructor using reflection

Tags: reflection, constructor, kotlin, user-input, invoke

For a simple machine language reader, I have a number of classes AaaInstruction, BbbInstruction, CccInstruction, etc. which are invoked as aaaInstruction(v1, v2, v3).  The idea is that the input is given in the form:

```
aaa v1 v2 v3

bbb v1 v2 v3

ccc v1 v2 v3
```

In the main class I use the following code:

```
var input = Scanner(System.`in`)

val instcode = input.next()

val cname: String = instcode.capitalize()+"Instruction"
```

How can I then invoke `cname(v1,v2,v3)`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to enumerate types in Kotlin, there isn't a Kotlin analogue to Java's `Class.forName()` method, and I do not think anyone has made a [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)-style library specifically for Kotlin yet, which means you would need to use Java reflection to get the Kotlin classes, and that's starting to sound pretty terrible. It's not great in the first place in my opinion - having an external input map to a class name sounds like a security nightmare.

Given your use case, there are a couple of approaches you could use.

First, you could implement a proper factory (a big switch statement would do, a map of constructors would be slightly more concise) instead of trying to build the name of the constructor you want from the opcode. I know that's probably what you're trying to avoid, but in my experience the problems you will run into avoiding it are bigger than the ones you are avoiding.

Second, if you are dead-set on using reflection somewhere, you can create all the opcode implementations as nested classes of a single meta-class, which you can then walk through using the `nestedClasses` property of `KClass`, and find the one whose `simpleName` property matches the opcode you're looking for. This is pretty ugly, though. You'll also need to include Kotlin's reflection runtime JAR, which is not included by default; see http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html.

Comment: There is no reason why using Java reflection to get Kotlin classes would be terrible. Kotlin supports two-way interop with Java reflection, with easy APIs to go back and forth between the two.

Comment: If you need to use interop _twice_ (Kotlin->Java reflection, then Java->Kotlin at some point later once you've found the class you're looking for), plus reflection, just to do the same logic that a simple `when` statement would achieve, then yes, I maintain that is terrible. Just because it is supported does not mean it is a sensible design choice.